# Como enviar dados através da ferramenta soapUI e como fazer manual?

Tags: soap

Gostaria de enviar informações através da ferramenta soapUI pra meu webService mais não sei como. Muitos me disseram para fazer manualmente e gostaria de saber como se faz dos dois jeitos !

Comment: Um pouco de código seria de grande ajuda para que nós ajudemos no seu problema, no mais, leia os links [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Elisson, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Sua pergunta foi suspensa porque está muito vaga. Talvez lhe falte um pouco de embasamento teórico ou simplesmente conhecimento sobre a ferramenta. Por favor, sinta-se à vontade para editar sua questão e esclarecer melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: O que posso adiantar é que o SoapUI é uma ferramenta que permite testar web services. Você só precisa criar um novo projeto com o endereço (URL) do web service que a ferramenta vai listar os serviços disponíveis e gerar todo o necessário para executar esses serviços e mostrar o resultado. Basicamente você consegue ver a mensagem enviada para o serviço (entrada) e o retorno (saída).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, recomendo você estudar um pouco sobre WebServices.

> SOAP
>
> É um protocolo de transferência de mensagens em formato XML para uso em ambientes distribuídos. O padrão SOAP funciona como um tipo de framework que permite a comunicação de forma transparente entre diversas plataformas com mensagens personalizadas.
>
> Aplicando este padrão em Web Services, geralmente usa-se o WSDL para descrever a estrutura das mensagens SOAP e as ações possíveis em um endpoint.
>
> Uma das maiores vantagens disso é que várias linguagens e ferramentas conseguem ler e gerar mensagens facilmente. Várias linguagens de programação permitem a geração de objetos de domínio, Stubs e Skeletons a partir da definição do WSDL, permitindo a comunicação remota via RPC através de chamadas a métodos remotod, inclusive com argumentos complexos, como se fossem chamadas locais.
>
> O problema desse padrão, é que ele adiciona um overhead considerável, tanto por ser em XML quanto por adicionar muitas tags de meta-informação..
>
> Overhead é geralmente considerado qualquer processamento ou armazenamento em excesso, seja de tempo de computação, de memória, de largura de banda ou qualquer outro recurso que seja requerido para ser utilizado ou gasto para executar uma determinada tarefa. Como consequência pode piorar o desempenho do aparelho que sofreu o overhead.(wikipedia)
> Endpoint, ou emPortuguês ponto de extremidade, é um sinal de terminação ou conclusão.(wikipedia)
> Um stub ou method stub, em português esboço de método, em desenvolvimento de software, é um pedaço de código usado para substituir algumas outras funcionalidades de programação. Um stub pode simular o comportamento de um código existente (como um procedimento em uma máquina remota) ou ser um substituto temporário para o código ainda a ser desenvolvido. Eles são portanto mais úteis em portabilidade, computação distribuída bem como no desenvolvimento e teste de software em geral.(wikipedia)

Mais sobre webservices:

http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each

Depois de entender um pouco sobre Webservices você pode ver os tutoriais abaixo.

Tutorial de como utilizar o soapUI:

https://sobretestes.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/soapui-4-5-1-ferramenta-para-teste-de-webservices-tutorial-basico/

Tutorial de como chamar um webservice em Java:

http://wehavescience.com/2013/03/16/criando-e-consumindo-um-webservice-utilizando-java-7-e-axis/

Comment: Uma resposta apenas por links é ruim pois se os links quebrarem, a resposta fica inválida.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: mutlei , melhorei a resposta.

Comment: elisson, a respota foi útil? Marca como certa ou vota nela.